# vba index match with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert an R1C1 vba formula into an "A1" type of code.

```
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=INDEX(C3,MATCH(RC[-1]&R2C6,C1&C5,0))"
```

in spreadsheet it is:
**=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(H2&$F$2,$A:$A&$E:$E,0))**

I tried the following but I am not getting the correct result, please guide.

```
    a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("C:C"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("H2").Value, Range("A:A"), 0) + _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("F2").Value, Range("E:E"), 0), 0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use `Evaluate`... `$A:$A&$E:$E` doesn't translate well to VBA.

Comment: How do I do that sir?

Comment: It is going to be quicker if you load the used ranges into arrays and loop the first dimension of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not straightforward to convert a formula like `=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(H2&$F$2,$A:$A&$E:$E,0)` to VBA, because of the `$A:$A&$E:$E`. You'd need to create an array that joins the values in column A and E. Additionally, `Match` when used with an array is slower than when used with a `Range`.

One workaround is just to use `Evaluate` here:

```
Dim a 
a = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(H2&$F$2,$A:$A&$E:$E,0))")
```

Comment: Hi BigBen, is this approach faster than the Application.WorksheetFunction/s (Index and Match) equivalent if there is one?